# The wait operation timed out and sql server store procedure transactions

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a C# code, which is as follows:

```
using(Sqlconnection con = new SqlConnection("my connectionstring");
using (var command = SqlCommand("mystoerprocedeure", con))                             
{
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 if (commandTimeout.HasValue)
  {
    command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout.Value;
  }
  var param = command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@myparam, datatableobject);                           
  param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;      
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

And here is the store procedure which gets called

```
ALTER PROCEDURE mystoreprocedure
@myparam mytabletype READONLY
AS
DECLARE @StartTranCount tinyint;
DECLARE @errmsg varchar(2000);

BEGIN TRY
 SET @StartTranCount = @@TRANCOUNT;
 SET @errmsg = 'ERROR: Unable to insert';

--Perform the actual INSERT
IF @StartTranCount = 0
BEGIN TRAN;

insert into abc (name, rollno)
select name, rollno from mytabletype

IF @StartTranCount = 0
COMMIT TRAN;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @StartTranCount = 0 AND
XACT_STATE() <> 0
ROLLBACK TRAN;
RAISERROR(@errmsg, 16, 1);
END CATCH;
```

I am getting a "The wait operation timed out" exception in c#, and when I retry to insert using the same object of my data table it gets inserted. And I see duplicate rows in my database table. But I am confused how it's possible as I have made a transaction in my store procedure.

Comment: Considering that that SQL isn't valid, `insert into table abc (name, rollno)`, *the reserved word `table` shouldn't be there) is that really your SQL?

Comment: @Larnu fixed that Thanks. Yes it's my sql I have shorten the insert query and change the table name, but main purpose of providing the SQL is, it's getting a table type parameter, and I am doing insertion using that.

Answer (score 0):

try to use TransactionScope in your code.

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
using (Sqlconnection con = new SqlConnection("my connectionstring")
using (var command = SqlCommand("mystoerprocedeure", con))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    if (commandTimeout.HasValue)
    {
        command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout.Value;
    }
    var param = command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@myparam, datatableobject);
    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ts.Complete();
}
```

Comment: what's the difference between using TransactionScope, and store proecedure transactions? if we are getting exception that transaction will not be commited anyway.

Comment: in my mind ,  store proecedure transactions only promise  transaction in your db ,  TransactionScope promise transaction  in your code scope by TransactionScope

Comment: I'he just made a sample application, forcefully raising timeout issue. keeping transactions in store procedure, it turns out, If we get timeout exception and we have transaction in our store procedure data will not be inserted in table.